# Center align a contact form on page with side by side text and input fields? [UPDATED]

Tags: html, forms, alignment

EDIT: I have updated both the CSS and the html. I have figured out the centering, but am still having trouble with the alignment of labels and fields.
I need for the input fields and labels to be lined up to where there is a perfect line running down the center of them, essentially dividing them because the labels are stacked on top of one another and input fields are stacked on top of one another.
The code below already resembled how I want it to look, other than that the form is on the left edge and my labels and input fields aren't perfectly lined up.

This is my form so far:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
            <form>
                <div>
                    Name: <input type="text" name="Name" size="40"/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Address: <input type="text" name="Address" size="50"/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    City: <input type="text" name="City" size="25"/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    State: <input type="text" name="State" size="25"/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Zip: <input type="text" name="Zip" size="25"/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Email: <input type="text" name="Email" size="40"/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Subscribe to our mailing list?
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" name="AddToList" value="yes" checked="checked" />Yes
                    <input type="radio" name="AddToList" value="no" />No
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Comments:<br/>
                    <textarea name="comments" cols="70" rows="10" placeholder="Expected value of input"></textarea>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="submit" />
                    <input type="reset" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

So far, the only CSS I have for this form is:

```
form {
display: inline-block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: left;
}
```

This is what I am trying to accomplish:
[image]

Any help or advice would be great and highly appreciated, I am really just dumbfounded by this one. I tried using some of the centering methods for tables, none of which worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
check this i just positioned it with css
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>index</title>
<style>label{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 2px;
}
input{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.text{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.text{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    
}

</style>

</head>

<body>
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <form>
            <div>
               
                <label> Name:</label>
                 <input type="text" name="Name" size="40"/>
                
            </div>
            <div>
                <label style="left:27px"> Address:</label>
                
                <input type="text" name="Address" size="50" style="left:27px;"/>
                
            </div>
            <div>
                <label style="right: 46px;">City: </label>
                <input type="text" name="City" size="25" style="right:46px;"/>
                
            </div>
            <div>
                <label style="right:48px">State:</label>
                 <input type="text" name="State" size="25"/ style="right: 49px;">
                
            </div>
            <div>
               <label style="right: 43px;"> Zip:</label> <input type="text" name="Zip" size="25" style="right: 44px;"/>
                
            </div>
            <div>
                
                <label style="bottom: 0px;" > Email:</label>
                 <input type="text" name="Email" size="40"/>
                
            </div>
            <div style="right: 180px; position: relative;" >
                <label>Subscribe to our mailing list?</label>
                
                <input type="radio" name="AddToList" value="yes" checked="checked" />Yes
                <input type="radio" name="AddToList" value="no" />No
                <br/>
                <br/>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <br>
                <br>
               <label style="top: 60px; left: 70px;"> Comments: </label>
                <textarea name="comments" cols="70" rows="10" placeholder="Expected value of input" style="left: 84px;  position: relative;"></textarea>
                <br/>
                <br/>
              
            </div >
            <div class="submit" style="right: 80px; position: relative;">
            <input type="submit" width="" />
            <input type="reset" />
        </div >
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked really well, thank you so much!!! I will definitely be setting some time aside to study this code so I don't run into this problem again. I appreciate the help with this very much!

Answer (score 0):

For centering things, try:

```
margin: auto; 
justify-content: center;
text-align: center
```

This should align all the contents in the page as well as the text also with margins being equal.

Second option:

```
margin: auto;
width: 80%
```

This will take only 80% of total width of parent element and will automatically be centered if that also doesn't work then remove margin: auto from second option.

Answer (score 0):

To center align, give the elements you want to align a class of "center", and then select the class in CSS. An example is :

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Email: <input type="text" name="Email" size="40" class="center"/>
  <br/>
</div>
```

EDIT : [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/) is where I found the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I am looking for and that is on me. I caused some confusion and edited my post to make it as clear as I can.